# How can I run the regedit.exe from a Perl script on Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: perl, windows-server-2008, registry

I have yet another subtle problem on Windows :(

The following one-line perl script doesn't work:

`perl -e "system('regedit.exe /s C:\my.reg');"`

It really runs regedit.exe tool (I'm sure since I tried to run it w/o "/s" and saw confirmation dialogs), but it doesn't create a key in the registry.

I tried to run 

`regedit.exe /s C:\my.reg`

in from windows shell (cmd.exe) and it works fine.

The original command works fine on Windows XP, but doesn't work on 2008 server.
So I suspect that this is system-related issue.

Comment: I solved my problem by changing the command to perl -e "system('cmd64 /c regedit.exe /s C:\my.reg');"

Answer (score 1):

Are you executing this with an elevated cmd prompt (i.e. admin privileges)?  Regedit requires this.